# Where does master.dacpac come from in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, build-tools, dacpac

We have some build tasks that run and for the life of me I can't figure out why the ms build tools isn't installing the master.dacpac file needed for the master and the msdb dacpac files.

Here's where it lives now:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SQLSchemas

Currently, in VS2019 Professional it is added with the Data Storage and Processing Workload. SQL Server Data Tools is a dependency for several other workloads, such as:

ASP.NET and web development
ASP.NET and web development tools
Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools
Cloud tools for web development
In MS Build Tools, I noticed that the dacpac file isn't generated after installing the Data Tools workload.

Am I looking in the wrong place? What is generating the master.dacpac and the msdb.dacpac in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SQLSchemas?

Comment: I don't think it is generated; it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lance Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10910450/lance-li-msft) suggested these files are indeed being installed, not generated And yes, there was a bug in VS 2019 Build Tools which was fixed in [16.4.1 version of Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16).

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment but this is not an answer quite yet.  Once the build tools are released and the question is answered I will mark it as the appropriate answer.

Comment: @rdelgado-incinc Sure, you're right.  And any update feel free to share here:)

Comment: This issue is fixed in the latest release of Visual Studio (16.4.1). I'll edit the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: I will update this as the answer when we get a chance to test! Thanks Dhruva and Lance!

Comment: @rdelgado-incinc Did you get a chance to test this? If yes, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: I have not tested this yet - I will test when I can.  Thanks for pinging me.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I looking in the wrong place? What is generating the master.dacpac
>   and the system.dacpac in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SQLSchemas?

As far as l know, the `master.dacpac` and `msdb.dacpac` files are just like templates which you will use as a default database in your project. They are being used in developing a database project in VS2019.

**Test**

I have installed a new VS2019 Professional version in my machine. Firstly, I installed  the workload `.Net desktop development` and the files were not generated in the target path. Then I installed the `Data Storage and processing` workload and found the files were installed. After that, I tried to install the corresponding module in the Build Tool, but that did not generate the files.

Based on this, I can confirm that this file is generated when you are installing  `Data Storage and processing` workload in the VS2019 IDE rather than Build Tool.

Further, for **Build Tool** which is used for building projects including database projects, the files will not be generated when installing Build Tool, it is just by designed.

**Sample**

```
<ArtifactReference Include="$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac">
      <HintPath>$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac</HintPath>
    <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>False</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
    <DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>master</DatabaseVariableLiteralValue></ArtifactReference>
```

When you reference the system database when developing in VS2019, the hintpath will be

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SQLSchemas`.
```

And `$(DacPacRootPath)` will choose  like   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE`.

But when you use Build Tool to build this project in another machine without installing VS2019, you could face [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10499) which was reported by some customers.

`>>`If you face it, you can refer to it and Microsoft seems to have a fix in the latest version of MSBuild Tool.

**In addition**, if you just want MSBuild Tool to generate the `master.dacpac` file in MSBuild folder, you can suggest a feature to [DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to reflect it.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thank you for your response.  So are you saying that this is indeed a bug/problem with the current Visual studio 2019 Build tools installer?

Comment: Yes, that's it. This's one issue the team are working on to get a fix :)